# How to get the numerical/integer format of date time using mysql or java?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime-format

I would like to convert the  May 1, 2017 12:15:00 PM so that it reads like so 1493612100000

Then convert it into string. Is it possible in Java and MySQL and how to do it?

Comment: Parse the `String` to a `Date` or `LocalDateTime` object, get the "millis" value from it knock yourself out. Problem is, you will lose time zone context, but since there's no TZ in your format, that's probably already a problem :P

Comment: What is "May 1, 2017 12:15:00 PM"? Is this a `String`? `Date`? `LocalDateTime`? Is it a database column? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You appear to have two basic problems, converting a date to a valid `Date` or `LocalDateTime` object, plenty of examples of that around; getting the millisecond value from said object, again, plenty of examples of that around. If you're not going to make some kind of effort to solve the problem, don't expect others to do the same.  If try something and get stuck, we're here to help

Comment: It would help if we knew if you were starting with this date in Java or in MySQL.

Comment: On a side note, you can convert a Java `LocalDateTime` into a `java.sql.Timestamp`, which JDBC can use to set various types of Date fields in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in MySQL in two steps.  First, convert the string timestamp to a `datetime` using [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), then convert that date to milliseconds since the epoch using [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

```
SELECT 1000*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(col, '%M %e, %Y %h:%i:%s %p')) AS millis
FROM yourTable
```

This will return milliseconds since the epoch, which is what your sample data is referring to.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I tried this and it returns all (NULL) data

Comment: I solved it using SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Start_Date) from MyTable...but not exactly the numerical value as shown in my question

Answer (score 0):

> What you mean `1493612100000`? If it is only comparable integer you
>   can use next solution.

**Mysql have function UNIX_TIMESTAMP it may be used like this:**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`table`.`date`) from `table` WHERE ...;
```

**To convert your string to date use:**

```
STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2017 12:15:00 PM', '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s%p')
```

**Together:**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE( ... ) )
```

Comment: *"I would like to convert the May 1, 2017 12:15:00 PM so that it reads..."* - Does `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` do that?

Comment: This is a copy of my answer, and the format mask is wrong.  There is a space after seconds and `AM/PM`.

Comment: There is not copy of your answer as mentioned in your comment it have difference in mask. That is first. And second: my answer show another function as its name as its params.

Comment: I am not sure what is 1493612100000 this is extracted automatically using this command Fieldcolumn.getTime() or exactly like so $F{start_date}.getTime()